# Simple Object-Oriented Programming in Matlab: "Too many output arguments"

Tags: matlab, oop

I am very new to programming in Matlab, I just want to try out a small OOP scenario, but it does not quite work as expected. Here's my code:

```
classdef testOOP 

    properties
        age = 0;
        subject = '';
    end

    methods
        function ret = getSubject(this)
            ret = this.subject;
        end

        function ret = getAge(this)
            ret = this.age;
        end
    end 
end
```

When I run the m file and try out the functions in the command prompt, I get the exception "Too many output arguments":

```
ans =

    testOOP

>> x = testOOP

x =

    testOOP

>> x.age = 4

x =

    testOOP

>> x.age

ans =

     4

>> x.getAge

ans =

     4

>> x.getAge()

ans =

     4

>> y = x.getAge()
??? Error using ==> getAge
Too many output arguments.
```

**I'd like to know why this is failing, even though it works when I use**

```
y = ans
```

Comment: I don't see any error, at which line do you get the error message?

Comment: If you scroll a bit in the second code block, at the end it says 
??? Error using ==> getAge
Too many output arguments.

Comment: Ah, totally blind, sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just found this nice tutorial: http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~murphyk/Software/matlabTutorial/html/objectOriented.html#2

It says there were changes to Matlab's OOP from version 2008b on.

I am using Matlab 2007b (should have mentioned it, sorry...), where the syntax is like this:

```
>> a = testOOP 
a =
    testOOP
>> getAge(a)
ans =
     0
>> y = getAge(a)
```

This finally works.

Answer (score 2):

I tried your code (now including the last line) and I don't get any error. There is only one explanation which comes to my mind:

- You created a broken class
- An instance was created
- You fixed the class, but as long as the old version is instanced, Matlab does not update the class definition.

Try `clear all`, which should delete all instances, then retry.

Comment: Your third point may be part of the issue, as Matlab does not find a new method I added.